# QT5: cannot deploy android app

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-emulator, qt5

I installed QT 5.1 about 2 hours ago with all the stuff required to create an android app using C++ / QT.

When I create a Qt Quick 2 Application i try to deploy it to see how it looks like. An emulator starts but the app doesn't start and when I quit the emulator, I have this message :

> :-1: error: Cannot deploy: no devices or emulators found for your package.

The emulator works fine. I'm on Windows 8 Pro 64 bits.
Why can't I deploy a generated app ?

Thanks a lot, Jean (:

Comment: I don't mean to be rude (even though it may sound to you like I am) but 2 hours is nowhere near enough for you to have done proper research on your problem. Please narrow the problem down before submitting it to us.

Comment: You actually right, I have not look for hours for my problem since I've strictly followed up a tutorial showing how to set up Qt Creator for android development. I've done all that he says to but it still won't work. I googled this error but I found a single post saying that he fixed the problem by installing 32bits support but my Qt Creator is already a 32 bits installation...
Do you have other hints for me ? (another (new) tuto? mine's from may 2013)

Answer (score 1):

you have to launch the avd form android sdk manager > tools > manage avds, unlock it then run your project.
for more information please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817758/deploying-android-applications-qt-5-1/18878922#18878922)

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to do the same as OP, encountered the same problem.

Make sure adb finds your device. Instructions here http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Make sure you are deploying the correct API version. Attempting to deploy a package with too high API version will cause Qt Creator to skip your device and fallback to the emulator.

You can find the API version you're using from Qt Creator "Projects" view from the android kit run settings under "Package Configuration" details. Check your device's android version and the corresponding API version from here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

I've successfully deployed my first application and everything seems to be working fine.