# Deploying android applications Qt 5.1

Tags: android, qt, deployment, qt5

I have been trying to deploy a simple Qt application to android but with no luck. Details are as follows

1. Qt Version : Qt 5.1.0 for Android (Windows 32-bit) downloaded from [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-android-x86-win32-offline.exe.mirrorlist)
2. Qt Creator version : Qt Creator 2.7.2

I have set the following options in Qt Creator

**Android configurations**

3. Android SDK location : C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717\sdk
4. Android NDK location : C:\android-ndk-r8e
5. Ant location : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
6. AVD name : AndroidAVD (API Level 17,armeabi-v7a)

**Kit Configuration**

7. Name of the kit : Android for arm(GCC 4.4.3,Qt 5.1.0)(default)
8. Device type : Android
9. Device : Run on Android
10. Sysroot : Its empty
11. Compiler : GCC (arm 4.4.3 )
12. Android GDB Server : C:\android-ndk-r8e\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver
13. Debugger : C:\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe
14. Qt Version : 5.1.0 (android_armv7)(C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe)
15. Deploy configuration of the Kit(for both Release and Debug) : 
    Deploy local Qt libraries and Use Local Qt libraries option is checked
16. OS : Windows 7 64 bit

**The Problem**

When I try to build,everything builds fine. I get libTheTestApp.so in my build directory.
Also the project directory now contains a folder named "android" containing the manifest file and some other files.

When I try to Run the app, the emulator starts but I can't find my app. If I close my 
emulator and return to Qt Creator I get the following error

Please wait, searching for a suitable device for target:android-17.
Error while building/deploying project TheTestApp (kit: Android for arm (GCC 4.4.3, Qt 5.1.0))
When executing step 'Deploy to Android device'

If I do "adb devices" while the emulator is running, I get the id of the running emulator

Also I tried searching the internet before posting this question here. I found [this link](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-qt/137cb2xax4/when-executing-step-deploy-to-android-device-with-qt-5-1-final).

My question is how do I deploy a Qt5 application to an android device? Are there any links 
which say how to do it? I am asking this because I have followed the instructions provided
in Qt5ForAndroidBuilding  link while building the app.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

I was successfully able to deploy a simple QT application to my android device. 
From what I understand ,Qt creator first tries to deploy the app to a device if it finds one. If no device is found, it tries to launch an AVD and deploys the application to the emulator.

"Please wait, searching for a suitable device for target:android-17."
Try targeting a lower api level by changing it in Projects->Selected Toolkit -> Run -> Package Configuartion -> Manifest

And also , make sure that the Ant location points to InstallLocation\ant\bin\ant.bat

Answer (score 4):

Video Build and deploy Qt apps to Android using Qt 5.1 on Windows  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nkhlhBwkjk.

Answer (score 1):

- You did not mention that whether you specified jdk location in Qt Creator or not.
- for ant location, please specify the path to bin/ant.bat file from ant directory.

For people who will see this post in the future:

Do not launch avd from Qt Creator, first run the avd from android sdk manager

- do not create your own avd, use the existing ones instead, as follows
- go to android sdk folder, open android SDK Manager > tools > Manage AVDs...
- there are two tabs at the top, go to "Device Definition" tab
- select any one avd and click on "Create AVD"
- from new window that comes up, select target api level, cpu/abi and check snapshot checkBox at the bottom of the window and press "ok" button.
- new window comes up with the specifications of created avd, click ok
  now you have a valid avd. Select it and press "start" button.
  wait until the avd is lauched, unlock it and run you project.

Answer (score 0):

For a good documentation on deploying to Android device:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-deploying-android.html
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/android-support.html
I had the same problem. To solve it I configured the app as it is presented in the links.
Be careful to start the device emulator from Android sdk->AVD Manager NOT from Qt Creator->AVD Manager.
And check to see if ant is correctly installed by run->cmd->ant -version.